# What’s the name of a matrix which commutes with its own transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology

Normal matrices commute with their conjugate transpose.
How are matrices which satisfy
$$AA^T=A^TA$$
called?

Comment: Do you mean a Normal matrix? Normal matrices commute with their hermitian adjoint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix

Comment: For real matrix, they are still normal and for complex ones I am not sure there is a name.

Comment: @RdBasha, no, there are normal matrices who do not commute with their transpose.

Comment: I don't think these kinds of matrices have a name. Notably, there is nothing that we can say about a matrix (up to matrix similarity) using only the information that $A$ commutes with $A^T$, since every $A$ is similar to such a matrix. More that that, we can say that every matrix $A$ is similar to a matrix $M$ that satisfies $M = M^T$, i.e. a "complex-symmetric" matrix.

Comment: @nicomezi, I’m referring to complex matrices.

Comment: Real matrices are included in complex ones. I am just saying that there is no name for this notion for complex matrices, as far as I know.